# Existence and uniqueness of the solutions to dy/dx=x(y)^(1/2)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know if anyone knows why

Solutions of the differential equation of $y'=x y^{1/2}$ has at least two solutions satisfying the initial condition $y(x_0) = 0$.

Is this because when you partial differentiate it wrt $y$, we get $x/(2y^{1/2})$ which is not continuous for everywhere?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please use [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your Maths so people can understand what you are asking

Comment: $y'/\sqrt{y}=x$ gives immediately $\sqrt{y}=x^2/4+C$ by integration. Thus $y=(x^2/4+C)^2$, $C$ arbitrary constant.

Comment: @JeanMarie  then $y(x_0)=0$ would suggest $C=-x_0^2/4$ and so you would have a single solution $y=\left(\dfrac{x^2-x_0^2}{4}\right)^2$ at least for $|x| \ge |x_0|$

Comment: @Henry That's it (At the time I wrote the comment, the OP had not initial conditions)

Comment: @Henry thank you so much for answering! but i wondering if this answers the fact that the differential equation has at least 2 solutions? I'm sorry i was taught very poorly on this topic

Comment: $y=0$ and $y(x)=(\max(0,x^2-c^2)/4)^2$, $c>0$, are also solutions.